# Getting ModemServiceMode with adb

Tags: adb, samsung, cellular-radio

On Samsung devices, how to get the ModemServiceMode page (*#0011#) with ADB commands?

[image]

Comment: Use ADB (`dumpsy activity`/`dumpsys window`) to find the activity name for that activity in your screenshot. Than use it to try launching the activity. Make sure to remove the activity from recent screen or set an appropriate flag in your intent to start activity from scratch. // Which Android device and Android version are you using?

Comment: @Firelord Thank you, my device is SM-A720F and android version is 8.0.0

Comment: I just tried this on Samsung Galaxy M21, Android 12 and got `com.sec.android.RilServiceModeApp/com.sec.android.RilServiceModeApp.ServiceModeApp` as the activity name. However, running `am start -n com.sec.android.RilServiceModeApp/com.sec.android.RilServiceModeApp.ServiceModeApp` returned `java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.sec.android.RilServiceModeApp/.ServiceModeApp } from null (pid=18865, uid=2000) not exported from uid 1001`

Comment: @Andrew I also encountered this error.